# unfortunately application has stopped?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android application, and there are no errors anywhere, but when i run it on the mobile phone, after the application opens and i click on a button, after a while it suddenly closes and gives me the message "unfortunately ** has stopped".

can someone please tell me what's wrong?

I did some research and found that this message comes when there is something wrong in the manifest. Here is my manifest, i cant figure out what's wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.tryagain"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

   </manifest>
```

here is my .java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;
ArrayList <Short> x=new ArrayList<Short>();

ArrayList <Short> y=new ArrayList<Short>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setButtonHandlers();
enableButtons(false);

int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
        RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

//why is the following statement here???
System.out.println("BUFFER SIZE VALUE IS " + bufferSize);

}

 private void setButtonHandlers() {
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.Start2)).setOnClickListener(btnClick2);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop2)).setOnClickListener(btnClick2);


 }

 private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
 ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
 }

private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
enableButton(R.id.Start2, !isRecording);
enableButton(R.id.Stop2, isRecording);

 }

int BufferElements2Rec = 1024; 

 int BytesPerElement = 2; // 2 bytes in 16bit format

 private void startRecording() {

recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
        RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

recorder.startRecording();

isRecording = true;

recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        writeAudioDataToFile();

    }
 }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
 recordingThread.start();
  }


  private void startRecording2() {

  recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
        RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

   recorder.startRecording();
   isRecording = true;

  recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        writeAudioDataToFile2();

    }
   },  "AudioRecorder Thread");
  recordingThread.start();
    }


private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
int shortArrsize = sData.length;
byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];

for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
    bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
    bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
    sData[i] = 0;
}
return bytes;
}

  private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
// Write the output audio in byte

String filePath = "/storage/sdcard0/Sounds/recording1.pcm";



short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];
// to convert sData from short to Short:


FileOutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while (isRecording) {
    // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format and stores it in buffer sData

    recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
// here u will write the new code: to store what was said in an array,,, here we are 
    Short sData1= sData[BufferElements2Rec];
    int i=0; 
    x.add(i,sData1);
    i++;

    System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
    try {
        // // writes the data to file from buffer
        // // stores the voice buffer

        byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);

        os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
    } 

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }

  try {
    os.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} //END OF WRITE TO FILE METHOD


private void writeAudioDataToFile2() {
// Write the output audio in byte

String filePath = "/storage/sdcard0/Sounds/recording2.pcm";



short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];
// to convert sData from short to Short:



FileOutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while (isRecording) {
    // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format and stores it in buffer sData

    recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
// here u will write the new code: to store what was said in an array,,, here we are 
    Short sData1= sData[BufferElements2Rec];
    int i=0; 
    y.add(i,sData1);
    i++;

    System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
    try {
        // // writes the data to file from buffer
        // // stores the voice buffer

        byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);

        os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
    } 

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try {
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} //END OF WRITE TO FILE METHOD


 private void stopRecording() {
// stops the recording activity
if (null != recorder) {
    isRecording = false;

    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();

    recorder = null;
    recordingThread = null;
}
}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnStart: {
        enableButtons(true);
        startRecording();
        break;
    }
    case R.id.btnStop: {
        enableButtons(false);
        stopRecording();
        break;
    }
    }
    }
    };

   private View.OnClickListener btnClick2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Start2: {
        enableButtons(true);
        startRecording2();
        break;
    }
    case R.id.Stop2: {
        enableButtons(false);
        stopRecording();
        break;
    }
    }
   }
   };


  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    finish();
   }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
  }
```

here is my logCat

```
   06-27 16:50:46.830: I/System.out(11939): BUFFER SIZE VALUE IS 2048
   06-27 16:50:46.980: D/libEGL(11939): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_vc4.so
   06-27 16:50:46.980: D/(11939): SpyHook inactive - could not find libspyhook.so [Symbol not      found: ] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.spy = 0)
   06-27 16:50:47.000: W/khrn_client(11939): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
   06-27 16:50:47.000: W/khrn_client(11939): init_window window 0x50eda0d8, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0
   06-27 16:50:47.030: D/OpenGLRenderer(11939): Enabling debug mode 0
   06-27 16:50:53.066: W/dalvikvm(11939): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fb72a0)
   06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939): FATAL EXCEPTION: AudioRecorder Thread
   06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:     length=1024; index=1024 
  06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939):  at        com.example.tryagain.MainActivity.writeAudioDataToFile(MainActivity.java:148)
  06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939):  at com.example.tryagain.MainActivity.access$4(MainActivity.java:125)
 06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939):   at         com.example.tryagain.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:84)
 06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace or logcat output? We are basically taking stabs in the dark right now.

Comment: better to post your java code and logcat also

Comment: This is a general error message telling you there was an exception...it doesn't necessarily mean that the problem is in the `manifest`, it could be anywhere. As commented, post your logcat, also a portion of the code at least the `onClick` for your `Button`

Comment: I can say that if the `Button` is suppose to start a new `Activity` then it will crash because you don't have a second `Activity` declared in your `manifest`

Comment: i added my .java file

Comment: That's good but we still need the logcat to know what the error is and where it is happening

Comment: There is some problem with Your buffer Size. Try to set "BytesPerElement" to 1 instead of 2. What happens, does it work?

Comment: i set "BytesPerElement" to 1, but it still doesnt work. the reason it was originally 2 is because im using "short" variable. @Opiatefuchs

Comment: could You tell me the value of shortArrsize in Your for-loop(int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++)? try to make a log and check this, I think the problem is somerwhere here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading what @codeMagic said, i read the LogCat ,then i doubled click on

```
      06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939):  at        com.example.tryagain.MainActivity.writeAudioDataToFile(MainActivity.java:148)
```

it showed me where is the problem which was

```
Short sData1= sData[BufferElements2Rec];
```

then i replaced it by

```
Short sData1= sData[i];
```

thanks for all who  helped me .

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
these lines

```
06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:     length=1024; index=1024 
06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939):  at com.example.tryagain.MainActivity.writeAudioDataToFile(MainActivity.java:148)
```

Tells you that at line number 148 you try to access index number 1024 in an array of length 1024. 
You should always run up to `length - 1`

Check line 148 (or post it in the comments if you don't understand what's wrong there).

Good luck

Comment: so i should replace: (BufferElements2Rec) with (BufferElements2Rec-1)?? @La bla bla

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer but will help you to read your logcat and debug more yourself and post most relevant code so we can help more efficiently and prevent downvotes and closings

If you look for the line after

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AudioRecorder Thread
```

it will give you the error

```
  06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:     length=1024; index=1024
```

Here you try to access an index in your `Array` that is the length of it (you are given the `Array` length and `index` you are trying to access at the end of the line) so it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since we know that `Arrays` start with an `index` of 0. Then find the first line that references your code

```
  06-27 16:50:53.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11939):  at        com.example.tryagain.MainActivity.writeAudioDataToFile(MainActivity.java:148)
```

this tells us that the exception occurs at line 148 of `MainActivity` in the `writeAudioDataToFile()` function